# Magento 2.1.3 to magento 2.1.6 upgrade possible Issue?

Tags: upgrade, security, magento-2.1.3, magento2.1.6

Magento ver 2.1.6  - Added on Apr 11, 2017.

Magento 2.1.6 contains over 15 significant performance enhancements when compared to 2.1.5
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.6CE.html

I want to know possible issue of upgrade magento 2.1.3 to 2.1.6.

Have anyone face any issue after upgrading magento version to 2.1.6

Magento said there is some issue with image resizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded magento from 2.1.1 to 2.1.6 and only faced the issue with image resizing. All images were not displayed on category pages.

However, it can be solved using the following command:
bin/magento catalog:images:resize